# Unable to compile template. The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using RazorEngine to render out some basic content.
It works great until I include any @Url syntax into markup.

If the markup contains an @Url I get the following error

> Unable to compile template. The name 'Url' does not exist in the
>   current context
>
> Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property
>   for more information.

```
<input type="hidden" id="totalPageCount" value="@(Model.Count / (Model.PageSize + 1)+1)">
<div class="row">
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.ResultSet)
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Preview", "Topics", new { Id = item.Id })" class="card">
                    <div class="figure">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(item.Path)" alt="image">
                        <div class="figCaption">
                            <div>getDate('@String.Format("{0:s}", item.CreationDate)');</div>
                            <span class="icon-eye"> @item.Views</span>
                            <span class="icon-bubble"> @item.Replies</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="figView"><span class="icon-eye"></span></div>
                        @if (item.Category == TimeData.Forum.Common.CommentCategory.Accident)
                        {
                            <div class="figType label label-danger">KAZA</div>
                        }
                        else if (item.Category == TimeData.Forum.Common.CommentCategory.RoadWorks)
                        {
                            <div class="figType label label-warning">YOL ÇALIŞMASI</div>
                        }
                        else if (item.Category == TimeData.Forum.Common.CommentCategory.Other)
                        {
                            <div class="figType label label-green">DİĞER</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <h2>@item.Name</h2>
                    <div class="cardAddress"><span class="icon-pointer"></span> @item.Address</div>
                    <div class="cardAddress"><span class="icon-map"></span> (@item.Latitude , @item.Longitude)</div>
                    <ul class="cardFeat">
                        <li><span class="icon-user"></span> @item.OwnerFullName</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: What version of the MVC framework are you using? 3 or 4 ?

Comment: You could try using single quotes around the `@Url` helper, like this `'@Url.Action()'` let me know if this works.

Comment: Mvc version is 5.2.2.0

Comment: change single quotes around '@Url.Action("Preview", "Topics", new { Id = item.Id })' but again give exception

Comment: What is the exception this time ?

Comment: Exception : An exception of type 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' occurred in RazorEngine.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to compile template. The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context



Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.

Comment: I don't see where you've closed your anchor tag, and it should also have a text in it if its a link like this `'<a href ='@Url.Action("preview", "topics", new {Id = item.Id })' class ="card">Text</a>'` the Text should be whatever string the anchor tag should have.

Comment: it is closed.  <a href='@Url.Action("Preview", "Topics", new { Id = item.Id })' class="card"> ..... </a>   . i control all html tag only img tag not closed  ( <img src='@Url.Content(item.Path)' alt="image">) other html elements are closed.

Comment: I see you have a div inside the anchor tag. Have you tried coding a simple link using the @Url helper to see if that works?

Comment: i write simple template but again give same excepttion   template = "Hello @Model.Name! @Url.Action(\"Preview\", \"Topics\") Welcome to Razor!";                                                
string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });